# C# - Extract Parts from Log File

Tags: c#, file, logfile

I have a log file, which contains errors and I was looking to try and extract certain parts of the message into another file.

I have pasted an example of the log below, I am looking to search through the log for "LEVEL: Error" and extract this line but also the "MESSAGE :" which is part of this error.

The problem with the "MESSAGE :" is that it is that it goes onto the next line.

```
2020-07-15-05.26.22.685000+060 XXXXXXXXXXX          LEVEL: Error
PID     : XXXX                 TID : XXXXX          PROC : XXXXXXXXX
INSTANCE: XXX                  NODE : XXX           DB   : XXXXXXXXX
APPHDL  : XXXXXXX              APPID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
AUTHID  : XXXXXXXX             HOSTNAME: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
EDUID   : XXXXX                EDUNAME: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
FUNCTION: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
MESSAGE : The error message is displayed here, however, it is not
          on the 1 line making it harder for me to work out how to
          extract it...
DATA #1 : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX


2020-07-15-05.26.22.685000+060 XXXXXXXXXXX          LEVEL: INFO
PID     : XXXX                 TID : XXXXX          PROC : XXXXXXXXX
INSTANCE: XXX                  NODE : XXX           DB   : XXXXXXXXX
APPHDL  : XXXXXXX              APPID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
AUTHID  : XXXXXXXX             HOSTNAME: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
EDUID   : XXXXX                EDUNAME: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
FUNCTION: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
MESSAGE : No error message, this is just a
          test line for the question on
          Stackoverflow.
DATA #1 : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

***Example of what the output file should look like:***

```
2020-07-15-05.26.22.685000+060 XXXXXXXXXXX          LEVEL: Error
MESSAGE : The error message is displayed here, however, it is not
          on the 1 line making it harder for me to work out how to
          extract it...
```

Comment: Can you post as text.  Easy to do.

Comment: Do you have a text file that has these log entries? If so, just select a couple of examples, copy, [edit] your question, paste the text. Select the text in the question and press Ctrl+K or click the icon that looks like `{}`. That will preserve the characters used in the original, so that people who are volunteering their time can more easily help you find an answer. Your current example has the space characters stripped from the message, which could be used when parsing...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was trying to do that in the first place hence the screenshot. I have amended this now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file has the same basic structure, Split each log by date pattern with regex and then use `SubString()` and `IndexOf()` to extract the desired strings.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Split each log by date pattern with regex
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}");
    var splitted = reg.Split(logfile);

    foreach (var log in splitted)
    {
        if (log.Contains("MESSAGE :"))
        {
            string Summary = log.Substring(0, logfile.IndexOf("\n"));

            // locate the message safetly
            int indexOfMessage = log.IndexOf("MESSAGE :");
            int indexofData = log.IndexOf("DATA");
            string message = log.Substring(indexOfMessage, indexofData - indexOfMessage);
            // Concatenate date and error level with the log message
            Summary = Summary + Environment.NewLine + message;
            Console.WriteLine(Summary);
        }
    }
  
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
-05.26.22.685000+060 XXXXXXXXXXX          LEVEL: Error

MESSAGE : The error message is displayed here, however, it is not
                                       on the 1 line making it harder for me to work out how to
                                       extract it...

-05.26.22.685000+060 XXXXXXXXXXX          LEVEL: INFO

MESSAGE : No error message, this is just a
                                       test line for the question on
                                       Stackoverflow.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried this but I am looking to loop through the entire log as there are multiple error messages which could be in it

Comment: is there a way this can be amended to loop through the file and output multiple entries?

Comment: @AGB_DT_54302290 Yes, split each log by date pattern with regex - please see updated answer

Comment: Thanks you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @AGB_DT_54302290 you welcome and you can mark it as an answer by clicking the checkmark sign.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO ;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;
namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>();
            Entry entry = null; ;
            string pattern = @"(?'name'[^:]+):\s+(?'value'[^\s]+)";
            string patternDate = @"^(?'date'[^\s]+)([^:]+:\s+)(?'level'\w+)";
            Boolean messageTrue = false;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if(line.Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("LEVEL:"))
                    {
                        entry = new Entry();
                        entries.Add(entry);
                        Match match = Regex.Match(line, patternDate);
                        entry.date = DateTime.ParseExact(match.Groups["date"].Value, "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.ffffffzz0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        entry.level = match.Groups["level"].Value.Trim();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (messageTrue && line.StartsWith(" "))
                        {
                            entry.message += " " + line.Trim();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern);
                            foreach (Match match in matches.Cast<Match>())
                            {
                                string name = match.Groups["name"].Value.Trim();
                                string value = match.Groups["value"].Value.Trim();

                                if (name != "MESSAGE") messageTrue = false;

                                switch (name)
                                {
                                    case "PID" :
                                        entry.pid = value;
                                        break;
                                    case "TID":
                                        entry.tid = value;
                                        break;
                                    case "PROC":
                                        entry.proc = value;
                                        break;
                                    case "INSTANCE":
                                        entry.instance = value;
                                        break;
                                    case "NODE":
                                        entry.node = value;
                                        break;
                                    case "DB":
                                        entry.db = value;
                                        break;
                                    case "APPHDL":
                                        entry.apphdl = value;
                                        break;
                                    case "APPID":
                                        entry.appid = value;
                                        break;
                                    case "AUTHID":
                                        entry.authid = value;
                                        break;
                                    case "HOSTNAME":
                                        entry.hostname = value;
                                        break;
                                    case "EDUID":
                                        entry.eduid = value;
                                        break;
                                    case "EDUNAME":
                                        entry.eduname = value;
                                        break;
                                    case "FUNCTION":
                                        entry.function = value;
                                        break;
                                    case "MESSAGE":
                                        string[] splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                                        entry.message = splitLine[1].Trim();
                                        messageTrue = true;
                                        break;
                                    case "DATA #1":
                                        entry.data = value;
                                        break;
                                    default :
                                        break;
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }


                }
            }

        }
    }
    public class Entry
    {
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public string level { get; set; }
        public string pid { get; set; }
        public string tid { get; set; }
        public string proc { get; set; }
        public string instance { get; set; }
        public string node { get; set; }
        public string db { get; set; }
        public string apphdl { get; set; }
        public string appid { get; set; }
        public string authid { get; set; }
        public string hostname { get; set; }
        public string eduid { get; set; }
        public string eduname { get; set; }
        public string function { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Made a minor change.  Was getting LEVEL instead of ERROR or INFO